# Keeping the size of a table the same while changing the number of elements in the table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a grid of boxes where the user can set the number of rows/columns. I want the overall size to stay exactly the same, and change the size of each element accordingly. When creating the table in javascript, I set the width and height of each element to 320px/number_of_columns. However, the overall size doesn't stay the same when the user changes the number of columns.

I set the margin, padding, and border size of the elements to 0 so that those don't add to the total size. I've also played with the properties of elements higher up on the tree (like the  tag itself) to no avail.

The weirdest part is that the table doesn't always get bigger when I add boxes, and there's no apparent pattern in the relationship between the number of columns/rows and total size. As I test out different options, the total size is always roughly the same, but gets slightly bigger or smaller, or has slightly different dimensions.

I'm perplexed. Can anybody shed some light on what's going on?

Here's the relevant JavaScript code:

```
var box_size = 320/size
for (var r=0; r<size; r++) {
    $('table').append("<tr></tr>");
};
for (var c=0; c<size; c++) {
    $('tr').append("<td class='grid' width='" + box_size + "px' height='" + box_size + "px'></td>");
```

And CSS code:

```
#table_grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.grid {
   background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
```

Here's a [link to the entire project on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collinksmith/2wrtaxdy/2/) so people can see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the float pixel issue.When the result is a float number its roundup the pixel. For example if number of column is 9 then result is- 35.55555555555556px which is equivalent of 36px. To skip this problem you can use % instead of pixel. But then you have to set table height and width first.

```
var box_size = 100/size
for (var r=0; r<size; r++) {
    $('table').append("<tr></tr>");
};
for (var c=0; c<size; c++) {
    $('tr').append("<td class='grid' width='" + box_size + "%' height='" + box_size + "%'></td>");
```

ans css

```
#table_grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
}
```

Take a look to my example at - http://jsfiddle.net/2wrtaxdy/3/